# Elastic elements on scroll with javascript and or CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there anyone who knows if there is a javascript library or some functions which allow me to add a elastic/rubber band effect for specific elements on scroll? So in example, when I scroll very fast and suddenly stop, those elements will move out of place for a bit and then move back to their original position like they are attached to a rubber band.

I tried to search for this but couldn't find it.

Anyone who knows anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use both ScrollMagic.js to control the scroll functionality and Animate.css to create the elastic effect.

Using ScrollMagic you can set a trigger at a specific screen location class/id/div etc. Upon which you can give the element a class from the Animate.css library e.g. Bounce.

[ScrollMagic.js](http://scrollmagic.io)

[Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)